# Angular 5 lazy loading Error: Cannot find module

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading, angular-router-loader

I would like to use lazy loading but I can not understand why it does not work, it gives me error "Cannot find module".
This is my environment:
- Angular 5.2.1
- .NET Core 2
- Webpack 3.10.0
- angular-router-loader 0.8.2
- @angular/cli 1.6.5
I tried different path in loadChildren always without success, i also temporarily disabled all the guards and the children routing. What did I do wrong?

**FOLDERS**

```
ClientApp
  app
    components
      users
        users-routing.module.ts
        users.module.ts
  app-routing.module.ts
  app.module.shared.ts
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: './components/users/users.module#UsersModule'/* ,
        canLoad: [AuthGuard] */
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/login',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/login'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
            { enableTracing: false }
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ],
    providers: [
        CanDeactivateGuard
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**users-routing.module.ts**

```
const usersRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: UsersComponent/* ,
        //canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'detail',
                canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
                children: [
                    {
                        path: ':id',
                        component: UserViewComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'edit/:id',
                        component: UserFormComponent,
                        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard],
                        resolve: {
                            user: UsersResolver
                          }
                    },
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: UserFormComponent,
                        canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuard]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                component: UsersListComponent
            }
        ] */
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forChild(
            usersRoutes
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class UsersRoutingModule { }
```

**users.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        UsersRoutingModule,
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        UsersComponent,
        UserFormComponent,
        UsersListComponent,
        UserViewComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UsersResolver,
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const AngularCompilerPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AngularCompilerPlugin;
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

module.exports = (env) => {
    // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    const sharedConfig = {
        stats: {
            modules: false
        },
        context: __dirname,
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
        },
        output: {
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    include: /ClientApp/,
                    use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.html$/,
                    use: 'html-loader?minimize=false'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
                    use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
                }
            ],
            loaders: [
                {
                  test: /\.ts$/,
                  loaders: [
                    'awesome-typescript-loader'
                  ]
                },
                {
                  test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
                  loaders: [
                    'angular-router-loader'
                  ]
                }
              ]
        },
        plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
    };

    // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
    const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
    const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        entry: {
            'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts'
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir)
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.browser#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
            })
        ])
    });

    // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
    const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
        resolve: {
            mainFields: ['main']
        },
        entry: {
            'main-server': './ClientApp/boot.server.ts'
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./ClientApp/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                name: './vendor'
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: path.join(__dirname, 'ClientApp/app/app.module.server#AppModule'),
                exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
            })
        ]),
        output: {
            libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
            path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
        },
        target: 'node',
        devtool: 'inline-source-map'
    });

    return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true, // Workaround for https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17863. Remove this if you upgrade to a fixed version of Angular.
    "strict": true,
    "lib": [ "es6", "dom" ],
    "types": [ "webpack-env" ], 
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [ "bin", "node_modules" ],
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false }
}
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot find module
>   './ClientApp/app/components/users/users.module'. ; Zone: angular ;
>   Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot find module
>   './ClientApp/app/components/users/users.module'.
>       at vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:34015
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117428)
>       at Object.onInvoke (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:5604)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invoke (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117427)
>       at Zone.run (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117178)
>       at vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117898
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117461)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:5595)
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117460)
>       at Zone.runTask (vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:117228)
>   Error: Cannot find module
>   './ClientApp/app/components/users/users.module'.
>       at http://localhost:5000/dist/vendor.js?v=AdjSBPSITyauSY4VQBBoZmJ6NdWqor7MEuHgdi2Dgko:34015:9 ... [truncated]

**EDIT**

[link to stackblitz for testing](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yktumw)

Comment: `app-routing.module.ts` is within `app` folder?

Comment: @VivekDoshi Yes it's right

Comment: @Luciano Do not edit your question with how you solved it. Instead, answer it below and accept it.

Comment: If you have an answer, please post it as an answer. Do not edit your question for this purpose.

Comment: Ok sorry guys and thanks for the edit

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have found two solutions (via the OP by edit):

1. Reference to the module, after it has already been resolved with an import statement:

   import { UsersModule } from './components/users/users.module';

then referencing this way:

```
{
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: () => UsersModule,
    canLoad: [AuthGuard]
}
```

2. I have added `ng-router-loader` to the application (`npm install ng-router-loader --save-dev`) and I set up Webpack like this:

   ```
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                include: /ClientApp/,
                //use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack'
                use: isDevBuild ? [{ loader: 'ng-router-loader' }, 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack'
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader?minimize=false'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/,
                use: 'url-loader?limit=25000'
            }
        ],
   ```

then referencing the module by path:

```
    {
        path: 'users',
        loadChildren: './components/users/users.module#UsersModule',
        canLoad: [AuthGuard]
    }
```

Comment: @wctiger same here, I wonder what was the reason. I've been working on my project for some time and one day it just stopped working.Yet I am certain the loadChildren path is correct. The first way saved my day as well, but it troubles me as to why it works.

Comment: But with the first way, I can't enable AOT any more since AOT doesn't support arrow function in decorators.

Comment: I was having the same problem in Angular 9.  Adding the import statement to my routing.ts file resolved it for me, even with the loadChildren property set to the path for the module.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this:

```
const rootRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'your-path', loadChildren: () => UsersModule }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

The currently accepted answer, which proposes to exchange the value of loadChildren from a string to a function, removes the possibility of AOT compilation when doing a production build.

What worked for me, was 
1) use absolute paths
2) Add the lazy loaded modules as a string array in angular.json under projects > 'projectname' > architect > build > options > lazyModules. The paths should be the same as defined under loadChildren.

So, in your case, I think this should work in your routing module:

```
loadChildren: 'app/components/users/users.module#UsersModule'
```

And in angular.json, add this at the location specified above:

```
lazyModules: ["app/components/users/users.module"]
```

Comment: the path in `lazyModules` must start with `src/`. i just tested. i m thankful for your answer as it lead me to know about that option in `angular.json`

Answer (score 2):

Supposing this is AppModule that handles lazyloading and the features of your system are of the same tree as it is:

```
routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'files-pannel',
        loadChildren: () => import('./module-folder/module-name.module').then(m => m.ModuleName)
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Its typo folder name is `Users` not `users` :

Change

```
'./components/users/users.module#UsersModule'
```

to

```
'./components/Users/users.module#UsersModule'
```

Comment: The folder name is user, i've edited the post. Sorry

Comment: Will you please remove `RouterModule` from users.module.ts and try again ? @Luciano

Comment: @Luciano , will you please create demo on stackblitz?

Comment: I've added a link to stackblitz in the post

Comment: @Luciano , please check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-issue, Make it working click on the first link , you are getting 2 link because of userRooutingModule , there is no need to put path and component there , it will automatically point the userComponent.

Comment: Ok this change make my stackblitz working, but the same change does not help in my application. Always Cannot find module

Comment: @Luciano,Then I think you have to find the issue by your self, I have made the stackblitz working, Let me know If there is any other way to help :)

Comment: Thanks Vivek Doshi, i think the problem is with the configuration of the webpack but i do not know what. I do not know how to configure the whole environment on stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

try to do n your user.module.ts:

```
import {UserRoutes } from './User.routing'

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        UsersRoutingModule.forChild(UserRoutes), //<-- for child
        RouterModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        UsersComponent,
        UserFormComponent,
        UsersListComponent,
        UserViewComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        UsersResolver,
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class UsersModule { }
```

Comment: Federico, i don't understand how to implement this, forChild is not a method of UserRoutingModule (it's inside the module)

Comment: yes cause you' re  exports: [
        RouterModule
    ] from your user routing .... Give a try!!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is an error with the path. Change the path.

For example, this solution works for me::

```
loadChildren: '../changelog/changelog.module#ChangelogModule'
```

`./folder` or `../folder` or `folder`

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same issue while loading my module I was getting this error
Error: Cannot find module 'app/users/users.module'
Then after figuring out it was error related to the path
This solution works for me hope it help anyone
In the route add this path

```
{
   path: 'users',
   loadChildren: '../app/users/users.module#UsersModule'
 }
```

Figure out the path of your module folder like folder or ./folder or ../folder

Happy Coding!!