# Lazy load Angular 5 error: $$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive

Tags: angular, angular-cli, lazy-loading

I'm using angular cli AoT compilation.
When I try to make a lazy load component following this **[tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)**, I got the error below:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function
TypeError: __webpack_require__.e is not a function
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:13), <anonymous>:15:29)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6554)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6538)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js:51)
    at webpackAsyncContext (eval at ./src/$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive (main.bundle.js:13), <anonymous>:15:29)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.loadAndCompile (core.js:6554)
    at SystemJsNgModuleLoader.load (core.js:6538)
    at RouterConfigLoader.loadModuleFactory (router.js:4543)
    at RouterConfigLoader.load (router.js:4523)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.eval [as project] (router.js:2015)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:92)
    at ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js:51)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
    at eval (zone.js:858)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4736)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1517)
```

Here are part of my codes:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'listes', loadChildren: 'app/component/list/list.module#ListModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**list-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { ListComponent } from './list.component';

const routes: Routes = [] = [
  { path: '', component: ListComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ListRoutingModule { }
```

**list.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { ListRoutingModule } from './list-routing.module';

import { ListComponent } from './list.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ListRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ ListComponent ]
})
export class ListModule { }
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './component/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './component/footer/footer.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DetailModule } from './component/detail/detail.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './component/home/home.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I already report it as an **Angular-cli Issue**. You can find it [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9775).

Is there anyone who experienced with the same issue and found a solution for this?

> Related bug:
>   [Angular 5 with Angular cli non-lazy loading modules in the router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48523411/angular-5-with-angular-cli-non-lazy-loading-modules-in-the-router)
>   (Not solved yet).
>
> Proposed solution:
>   https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/1936:
>
> ```
> { path: 'listes', loadChildren: () => ListModule }
> // it doesn't do lazy loading
> ```

**Important information:**

```
Angular cli: 1.7.0
Angular: 5.2.0
```

My regards

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I cloned and reproduced the issue using your posted GitHub code. In order to fix, your @angular/cli global and devDependencies packages must be at 1.7.2

```
npm remove -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.7.2
npm remove @angular/cli
npm add @angular/cli@1.7.2 --save-dev
```

Now the @angular/cli package in your devDependencies matches the global version and it is set to 1.7.2 where that issue is resolved.

Comment: thanks, I got this problem before and it works fine, after one week I got it again! is that normal?

Answer (score 60):

I got the same issue. I solve it Just stopping the cli server and start it. Error is gone if you done your code correctly.

Comment: Helped me. While CLI server was running I added dependency to a lazy loaded module (by mistake). After server reboot the error has changed and it turned out there was missing service injector.

Comment: didn't believe ur answer at first time but it worked like a charm.... thanks so much

Comment: This fixed it for me too... derp.

Answer (score 11):

There is an open bug on angular-cli **1.7.x**: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9488#issuecomment-368871510

Downgrade to **1.6.8** solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same issue.fix it by using

```
 {path:'listes' ,loadChildren: ()=>ListModule} not {path:'listes' ,loadChildren: 'app/component/list/list.module#ListModule'}
```

Comment: I don't think ListModule will be lazy loaded anymore because doing `()=>ListModule` you'll have to _touch_ the class so the module will be eagerly loaded. Please confirm, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Please see this comment on the 1.7.x bug. The issue seems to be importing the lazy loaded module into the AppModule. Removing that import fixed the issue for me: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9488#issuecomment-374037802

Answer (score 0):

As for me the problem was in importing ChildModule after AppRoutingModule in AppModule. Reordering them fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks! It really helped, AppRoutingModule should be last in imports array.

Answer (score 0):

According to me the problem is that you may be lazy loading more than one module on same routes in same routing file. I also faced similar problem and change the name of one of the route

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and managed to solve it by adding my lazy loaded modules to my angular CLI config file (angular.json).
See my answer here:
[Angular 5 lazy loading Error: Cannot find module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48441418/angular-5-lazy-loading-error-cannot-find-module/55516363#55516363)

Answer (score -4):

In your app.module.ts, did you import ListModule  ?

I faced same issue, and was able to fix it by removing lazy loaded modules from imports in app.module.ts

Comment: What I want to d is lazy loading. If it is not lazy loading, it works perfectly

Comment: Yeah that's why I ask you to remove ListModule from app.module.ts if you imported it. Dunno why you missread my answer

Comment: I never import ListModule into app.module.ts